# Ignoring rows while using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, database

I would like to skip 1st row from the csv I am loading.
Is there any option for that while using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`IGNORE 1 LINES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) **or** `IGNORE 1 ROWS`:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'example.txt' INTO TABLE table_name
IGNORE 1 LINES

-- or

LOAD DATA INFILE 'example.txt' INTO TABLE table_name
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```

> The `IGNORE number LINES` option can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use `IGNORE 1 LINES` to skip over an initial header line containing column names.

Comment: IGNORE 1 LINES is removing the columns of the file. The first rows of the file should be removed. Please think the .csv as row and columns.

Comment: `Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'column_name' at row 1")`  because I tried using IGNORE 1 LINES and IGNORE 1 ROWS together and it didn't help.

Comment: What do you mean by *removing the columns of the file*? This command doesn't edit your file. You have to use one of these. You should also share your current `LOAD DATA` command.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, It helped. :) ;)